# Extension method on FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using reactive forms and trying to create an extension method on `FormGroup`. My code is here:

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

declare module '@angular/forms' {
  interface FormGroup {
    setErrorForControl: (error: string, control: string) => FormGroup;
  }
}

FormGroup.prototype.setErrorForControl = function (error: string, control: string) {
  let errors = this.controls[control].errors;
  errors = errors ? errors : {};

  errors[error] = true;

  this.controls[control].setErrors(errors);

  console.log(this.controls[control].errors);
};
```

At first, this code doesn't compile. It says:

> `FormGroup` only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

I would like to use my method in code like this:

`this.myForm.setErrorForControl('someError', 'nirstName');`

Basically I would like to pass control name and error name and this method should set error in form.

**UPDATE:**

I can achieve this by adding:

```
FormGroup.prototype['setErrorForControl'] = function (error: string, control: string)
```

In the code I can do:

```
(<any>this.myForm).setErrorForControl('custom', 'FirstName');
```

Problem is because it doesn't exist on `FormGroup` type. Any solution?

Comment: The only issue with your suggestion is I can access only to `setValidityForControl()`. All others types are hidden.

Comment: Did you had any success on this? I am trying the very same thing.

Answer (score 4):

You need to import the class you want to extend, otherwise TypeScript doesn't know it's a class. If it thinks it's just an interface, it won't allow you to access `prototype` because interfaces don't exist at runtime.

```
import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms";

declare module '@angular/forms' {
  interface FormGroup {
    setErrorForControl: (error: string, control: string) => FormGroup;
  }
}

FormGroup.prototype.setErrorForControl = function (error: string, control: string) {
  let errors = this.controls[control].errors;
  errors = errors ? errors : {};

  errors[error] = true;

  this.controls[control].setErrors(errors);

  console.log(this.controls[control].errors);
};
```

See example here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/add/operator/map.ts

Comment: Do you have error: 'FormGroup' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here ? I was following similar example for Observables. But simply doesn't work.

Comment: I have that error if I forget to import the type when declaring an interface on top of it.

Comment: I still have that error and I updated example.  I already using import. I followed this approach for extending observable: https://blog.angular-university.io/debug-rxjs/ But something is wrong with forms.

Comment: What is your version of TypeScript. I am using 2.4.2 and it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using `2.5.3`.

Comment: Can you navigate to Angular's type definition for `FormGroup`? The only thing I can think of is that `FormGroup` is an interface in your version of Angular. If that's true, extensions won't work.

Comment: Here is definition: `export declare class FormGroup extends AbstractControl` and version of `@angular/forms` is 4.3.2.

Comment: I also checked the definition for `FormGroup` on Angular's master branch, and found it to be a class. That leads me to believe that you may not be importing that class in to the file where you are extending it (`import { FormGroup } from "@angular/forms"`). If that's true, it generates the same error as if it were an interface (because your file defines it as an interface).

Comment: try `declare module '@angular/forms/src/model' {` instead

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `FormGroup` as `interface` which is basically declaration of its type. But then you are trying to adjust its prototype, and you can do this only with a value, not with a type.

I would suggest creating your own wrapper for this and use it instead:

```
export class MyFormGroup extends FormGroup {

  setErrorForControl(error: string, control: string) {
    let errors = this.controls[control].errors;
    errors = errors ? errors : {};

    errors[error] = true;

    this.controls[control].setErrors(errors);

    console.log(this.controls[control].errors);
  }

}
```

Then you can use it:

```
this.myForm = new MyFormGroup(...);
this.myForm.setErrorForControl('someError', 'firstName');
```

Comment: But I want to extend existing type, I don't want to create new type.

Comment: Not sure it's possible, I guess it's not. But you definitely need to extend the class itself, not just its type. What is wrong with extending the class as I suggested? I think that is the way you should do it, as monkey patching existing classes is generally not a good practice.

Comment: I simply don't want to create new type and even if I do that I will need to extend some other types like `FormBuilder` etc.

Comment: @MartinAdámek, `FormGroup` is defined as a class in an existing module. re-defining it as an interface should simply add properties to the class (a class and interface with the same name is effectively the same as merging those types together in to a single class).